# What spellchecker does TeXShop use?

Tags: texshop

What spellchecker does TeXShop use? The motivation for this question is that the spellchecker accepts some controversially spelled words (like "homogenous"), which I didn't add to ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary

Comment: Have you installed cocoAspell? If not you are using the standard Apple dictionary.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Herb Schulz commented, TeXShop uses the Apple dictionary. "Homogenous" is an outdated biological term included in the Apple dictionary.